# Permanent link to a HTML5 video source on YouTube

Tags: video, youtube, html5-video

I am trying to embed a video hosted on YouTube ([WebM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) file) and play it using a specially modified HTML5 video player.

The video source looks like this:

> http://o-o.preferred.comcast-iad1.v10.lscache7.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams=id%2Cexpire%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Csource%2Cratebypass%2Ccp&fexp=906012&itag=43&ip=69.0.0.0&signature=91B4CE473CA09CFC2A14817849C322D73C7D0BCF.36D7C4C71CA91346FDB2C25CACF785CEC3F38D30&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&expire=1327038316&key=yt1&ipbits=8&cp=U0hRTFBOVl9GUENOMV9ISFpEOndPbDNaZ3lfMnp1&id=74c1f46c77a244d8

The problem I encounter is that the link is temporary, so it expires. How do I make this link permanent or get another one that is permanent?

Answer (score 0):

The only YouTube player API that supports [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5)  is the iframe API.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround to make it permanent video url is to use this site: http://youtubeinmp4.com/. Passing the youtube url to this site -> it'll give you a permanent url of that youtube video -> embed this url into your HTML source tag. Hope that helps.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.